# Angular <select> field not responding to clicks only for certain mobile devices

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation

I am having a problem with a  dropdown field in my Angular project, using Foundation. For certain screen sizes (like iPhone 6/7/8 and Galaxy S5 in the Chrome mobile emulator), the problem is hard to explain, it's so weird.

On most mobile devices, I can click in the select field no issues, the clickable area is perfect, it's the actual size of the field. But when I switch to the size of an iPhone 6/7/8 (375x667 pixels) nothing happens when I click in the select field. Experimenting with the screen size, I found as the screen size reaches a width of 375, and as the length gets shorter, the clickable area seems to shrink, creeping towards the top of the select field, until at a certain point it's too small to click on and nothing happens:

here is my html:

```
  <div *ngIf="!isQuote() && terms" class="cell medium-8 small-12 text-right">
    <span class="hide-for-small-only">Change policy term:</span>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedTerm" (change)="onSelectedTerm()" *ngIf="terms.length > 0">
      <option *ngFor="let term of terms"
              [value]="term.policyNumber + '/' + term.effectiveDate">
            {{ term.effectiveDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }} - {{ term.expirationDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

I have tried all sorts of solutions. Moving the code to different parts of the screen, adding css, removing css, changing he size of the column. Nothing works

Hoping someone has a solution to this

Comment: Try to inspect , there might be any other elements which are overlapping the select

Comment: Tried that, even put the select in it's own little space. Didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion